Automatically changing data type with QML file in QGIS attribute table
In QGIS 3.34, I'm working on a project where we collect data in the field; thus, we are using QField. As part of this, I create a shapefile that has some empty attributes to be filled in by field technicians.
In QGIS, I use the Refactor tool, as described at Changing data type in QGIS Attribute table, to change text strings to 100 characters and two of the numeric attributes to decimal instead of integer.
I can export this layer as a .qml file, but when I load it for another file, none of the attribute data types I changed actually load. Can .qml files help here, and if not, is there any way to automatically have these changes applied to future versions of the shapefile?
We have a new QGIS project every month with a different shapefile but the same format.

The attribute datatypes are properties of the dataset/featureclass (a shapefile in your case). A .qml just points to the dataset and stores properties like symbology, definition/provider query filter, etc. You won't change attribute datatypes for a dataset by applying a .qml to it.  Either set the datatypes for your shapefile when you originally create the dataset or have a workflow that includes the refactor fields tool afterwards. You could automate the workflow with a model.

Ah, I see, that makes sense. I was getting confused because the .qml file we currently use changes the formatting of the data fields, but not the datatype itself. Thanks for the model link!

@user2856 worth adding your comment as the answer. Seems to have answered the question.

The attribute datatypes are properties of the dataset/featureclass (a shapefile in your case). A .qml just points to the dataset and stores additional properties like symbology, definition/provider query filter, etc.
You can't change attribute datatypes for a dataset by applying a .qml to it. Either set the datatypes for your shapefile when you originally create the dataset or have a workflow that includes the refactor fields tool afterwards. You could automate the workflow with a model.
